# How to pass a blank / empty argument to a macro in Rust?

Tags: macros, rust

In some cases you may want to pass in an argument to a macro which is either some text, or *nothing* (blank space, as if nothing was written).

Given this starting point:

```
macro_rules! testme {
    ($var:ident, $code:block) => {
        for i in 0..10 {
            let $var = i;
            { $code }
            if $var > 5 {
                println!("over 5");
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    testme!(myvar, {
        println!("{}", myvar);
    });

}
```

We may want `var` to *optionally* be mutable, assuming the macro body is larger then in the example above, its best not to duplicate the entire macro.

```
macro_rules! testme {
    (private $var:ident, $code:block, $var_qual:tt) => {
        for i in 0..10 {
            // imagine this is a lot more code :)
            let $var_qual $var = i;
            { $code }
            if $var > 5 {
                println!("over 5");
            }
        }
    };
    (mut $var:ident, $code:block) => {
        testme!(private $var, $code, mut)
    };
/*
    ($var:ident, $code:block) => {
        testme!(private $var, $code, )
        //                          ^ how to pass in a blank argument?
    };
*/
}

fn main() {
    testme!(mut myvar_mut, {
        myvar_mut += 10;
        println!("{}", myvar_mut);
    });
/*
    testme!(myvar_immutable, {
        println!("{}", myvar_immutable);
    });
*/
}
```

As far as I can tell there is no way to pass in a an empty argument, uncomment the `/**/` comments to see the error.

---

Is it possible to pass in an empty argument to a macro to make an example like this work?

Comment: Why would one want that? In case of text input it could just be an empty string instead of nothing.

Comment: @ljedrz, Text is quite a different case, this is an optional *keyword*, so its not possible to pass it as an argument so easily. I'm using a macro that acts as an iterator and takes a the name of a variable to declare, this may need to be mutable or not - can post a link to original code - but not sure its needed.

Comment: Nah, I can see it now; I guess I'm just not used to relying on macros that much, it's a whole different class of issues than with regular code.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know its not possible to pass in blank / empty arguments.

It is possible however to pass in a locally defined macro which optionally adds a prefix.

Working example:

```
macro_rules! testme {
    (private $var:ident, $code:block, $var_qual_macro:ident) => {
        for i in 0..10 {
            // imagine this is a lot more code :)
            let $var_qual_macro!($var) = i;
            { $code }
            if $var > 5 {
                println!("over 5");
            }
        }
    };
    (mut $var:ident, $code:block) => {
        macro_rules! var_qualifier { ($v:ident) => { mut $v } }
        testme!(private $var, $code, var_qualifier)
    };
    ($var:ident, $code:block) => {
        macro_rules! var_qualifier { ($v:ident) => { $v } }
        testme!(private $var, $code, var_qualifier)
    };
}

fn main() {
    testme!(mut myvar_mut, {
        myvar_mut += 10;
        println!("{}", myvar_mut);
    });
    testme!(myvar_immutable, {
        println!("{}", myvar_immutable);
    });
}
```

Take care when nesting macros like this that the name of the macro (`var_qualifier` in this case) is isn't the same name used inside a different macro since the name will be silently shadowed.